# How to put media buttons on the lockscreen with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, notifications, exoplayer, lockscreen

I am using ExoPlayer (https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and custom notifications.

I want to access my music player from lock screen and headphone like in google play music and wync.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For playback controls on the lock screen you need to do a [MediaStyle notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle).

If you want to have an artwork as the lockscreen background you need to support MediaSession and maintain the metadata of the session properly:

```
new MediaMetadata.Builder(track)
   .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, bitmap)
   .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, bitmap) 
   .build();
```

Comment: Hyper link not working , share the example for media style

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Exoplayer with `PlayerNotificationManager`, And I used `MediaSessionConnector` and `TimelineQueueNavigator` to build notifications for the lock screen and background image for the lock screen.

Here, is my question with the Exoplayer team which is resolved for android 11 and above, regarding how to use `MediaSessionConnector`:

[Why PlayerNotificationManager not showing Notification on startForeground in Android 11(R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65842077/10954249)

Now, I just added a bitmap **(using putParcelable())** for the current session track for MediaDescriptionCompact which will be set to the current `MediaSession` internally.

Here is the code for that:

```
val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(serviceContext, "DPS_APP")
mediaSession.isActive = true
mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession).also {
                it.setQueueNavigator(
                    object : TimelineQueueNavigator(mediaSession) {
                        override fun getMediaDescription(
                            player: Player,
                            windowIndex: Int
                        ): MediaDescriptionCompat {
                            val data: MediaMetaData =
                                getEmptyOfNullMedia(player)
                            isBitmapAvailable(getCurrentMediaArt(data))
                            val extras = Bundle().apply {
                                putString(
                                    MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE,
                                    getCurrentTitle(data)
                                )
                                putString(
                                    MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST,
                                    getMediaTitle(data)
                                )
                                putParcelable(
                                    MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART,
                                    sessionCurrentBitmap
                                )
                            }

                            return MediaDescriptionCompat.Builder()
                                .setIconBitmap(sessionCurrentBitmap)
                                .setExtras(extras)
                                .build()
                        }
                it.setPlayer(mPlayer)
            }
```

Here is a small brief on that how to refresh or invalidate MediaSession in the given below issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5494