# Why PlayerNotificationManager not showing Notification on startForeground in Android 11(R)?

Tags: android, android-notifications, exoplayer

I am using the PlayerNotificationManager with Exoplayer and upto Android 10 Notification Tray is visible on startForeground() but in one of my phone when I upgraded to Android 11, the Notification Tray for media player stopped showing.

Please Help!!

Here I debugged on Google Pixel Now:

Working on Google Pixel android 11 but Not on Samsung G973F.
Why this is not working on Samsung??

Comment: To have media controls appear in the notification tray, you need to have the notification for playback turned on for each app in the settings. !

Comment: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/70400876?hl=en check this link.

Comment: already visited, notification playback is already turned on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I arises the issue On git ExoPlayer, the it's an device specific Issue,
so, here is the link of that issue,

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8500

Use MediaSessionConnector with ExoPlayer PlayerNotificationManager and MediaSessions:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/mediasession

Here there is use of MediaSession and MediaSessionConnector in more brief:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/supporting-mediasession

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go, i have not tested this but i think this will work,

```
// Create a media session. NotificationCompat.MediaStyle
// PlayerService is your own Service or Activity responsible for media playback.  
val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService")

// Create a MediaStyle object and supply your media session token to it. 
val mediaStyle = Notification.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)

// Create a Notification which is styled by your MediaStyle object. 
// This connects your media session to the media controls. 
// Don't forget to include a small icon.
val notification = Notification.Builder(this@PlayerService, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setStyle(mediaStyle)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_logo)
        .build()

// Specify any actions which your users can perform, such as pausing and skipping to 
the next track. 
val pauseAction: Notification.Action = Notification.Action.Builder(
        pauseIcon, "Pause", pauseIntent
    ).build()
notification.addAction(pauseAction)
```

Check this link for complete guide
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html

Comment: i m using exoplayer "PlayerNotificationManager" which already doing this code internally you mentioned here

Comment: Check if you are using the latest version of lib!? you can also report this to expo player at github !